# Template classes

Tags: c++, class, templates, linked-list

I'm getting an error with my template class and I cannot seem to figure out why.
I need a template argument list (which I beilieve is ) but I cannot seem to figure out where it goes.

```
    template <class G>
    ostream& operator << (ostream &destFile, const LinkedList &list)
    {
       nodePtr ptr;
       int i;
       for (ptr = list.head, i = 1; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next, i++)
           destFile << i << ": " << ptr->item << endl;
       return destFile;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `nodePtr`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: You "get an error", and I cannot seem to figure out why you don't want to tell us what this error is. Is this some sort of trick question, or a test? Are you with Google?

Comment: the definition of nodePtr is in the code. but not shown here.

Comment: If it's not shown here then how are we supposed to know if it pertains to your problem (as it certainly appears to)? Hint -- show _any_ relevant code!

Answer (score 4):

My guess is `LinkedList` is a template class, and you need to write this instead:

```
template <class G>
ostream& operator << (ostream &destFile, const LinkedList< G > &list)
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if `LinkedList` is a template but `nodePtr` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need `std::list<G>` instead of `LinkedList` (or perhaps your `LinkedList` is a template, then write `LinkedList<G>`)